# OpenWRT very slow Lookup / DNS? (TP-Link WDR4300)

Tags: openwrt, connection

Running OpenWRT Chaos Calmer 15.05 on the TP-Link WDR4300 lookup is taking multiple seconds. E.g., +5 seconds to find google.com.

In the browser you see "Looking up domain.com" for that time. After it has a connection, it works fine with the appropriate speed.

Also pinging to a domain takes the same amount of time (~5 seconds) and sometimes first results in "Request timed out" and after a while it finds it and starts the ping. Then also pinging will show responses in a fast correct way.

Hence, I reinstalled OpenWRT upgraded to 15.05.1, but still the same issue. I reflashed it to the original firmware of TP-Link and found that there is no issue then. I also installed another router, and also with this router there is no issue, lookup is fast, connection is fast.

Concluding, it should have something to do with the OpenWRT installation, since TP-Link firmware works well on the same TP-Link router & also another router works well.

Now installed 15.05.1 again. However, the issue is still there.

Note #1, now running a clean install of 15.05.1, no specific software or firewall rules installed. With all installations (OpenWRT 15.05, TP-Link original firmware, other router) I tested the connection via cable as well as via WiFi, this makes no difference for any of them.

Note #2, on the local network all connections work fine, pinging and other requests respond within the expected time frame.

Note #3, tests have been executed from multiple devices.

Anyone here that has an idea how this slow initiation of connection is possible & how this can be solved?

Thanks for your help, really appreciated.

Comment: If you change the DNS servers to something other then DNS servers provided by your ISP what happens?

Comment: Hi Ramhound, that seems to solve the problem. I have changed the DNS-settings to use a public DNS-server (8.8.8.8) and cleared the DNS cache on my computers as well. Now it works. Thanks a lot. One thing remain strange that with TP-Link firmware and with another router DNS is resolved normally & with OpenWRT it needs an open DNS-server. However, thanks a lot, I can use internet in a normal way again :-)